# Returning most recent record, grouped by one field whilst returning another

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to return the most recent record grouped on a specific ID, but I need to return the unique identifier (change_guid) from each returned record so that I can use it later.

Using the below correctly returns 28,908 records:

```
SELECT account_id, MAX(InsertDateTime) FROM change_records_archive WHERE change_type = 'Programme' GROUP BY account_id
```

I need to somehow include change_guid so without including it in the grouping. I've considered using an OUTER/CROSS apply, returning the Top 1 per account_id ordered by InsertDateTime Desc, but that doesn't apply the 'grouping' correctly.

Can someone please advise on what the best approach is for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: or `order by InsertDateTime desc limit 1 `

Comment: `LIMIT` isn't a keyword in T-SQL, @KamiKaze .

Comment: okey, `SELECT TOP(1)` .. the main purpose here is to sort in reverse order and choose one

Comment: @Larnu That's the ticket, how embarassing, it'll teach me to look properly in future!

Comment: Answered kindly by @Larnu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group